# Кросс-доменные cookie не видит сервер

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cross-domain

Скрипт на сайте `http://client` делает кросс-доменный ajax запрос на сервер `http://server`. Хочу, чтобы сервер увидел cookie с этого сайта.

Установлю cookie:

```
document.cookie = 'visitorId=123456;expires=Mon, 31 Jul 2017 00:00:00 UTC;path=/";
```

Делаю запрос:

```
var ajaxData = [];
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://server', true);
request.withCredentials = true;
request.onload = function () {}
request.send(ajaxData);
```

Сервер отвечает:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://client
```

Но в Request Headers уходят куки, установленные для `http://server` (если я правильно понимаю). Это так и должно быть и как мне на сервере увидеть куки сайта-клиента?

Comment: Куки дальше домена и его поддоменов видны не могут быть.

Comment: @Visman то есть только отдавать нужную куку на сервер через `POST`?

Comment: Для чего вам видеть на одном домене куки другого домена?

Comment: что-то типа "удалённой корзины". на сайте-клиенте висит виджет корзины. посетитель получает уникальный id в куки, по которому будет идентифицироваться корзиной. содержимое корзины складывается на сервер кросс-доменными запросами. Когда понял, что куки не видны - стал отправлять visitorId просто в теле ajax-запроса.